# How to create a circle with ArcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-engine, circle

I want to create a circle with IPoint P and radius r in ArcEngine and then I need to cast it to an IGeometry.  Does anyone know how to do this?

ESRI ArcEngine 10 VS2010 C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it

```
ISegmentCollection p = new PolygonClass();
p.SetCircle(mousepoint, 20);
IGeometry circleGeo = p as IGeometry;
```

Comment: Kudos for this.  You are correct, and I don't think a lot of people know about the SegmentCollection and the various Set methods that get used along with it.  This answer adds greatly useful information to the gis.stackexchange pool.

Comment: @celticflute sorry to report that it doesn't work properly after some testing

Comment: I'm curious - what kind of test did it fail?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall it created the circle in the wrong place

Comment: Were you converting your mousepoint into mapcoords and projecting if necessary?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall I think I was handling the projection correctly.  I did keep that in mind.

Comment: @Kirk, iterationx: I just tested this and seems to work perfectly for me...

Answer (score 2):

EllipticArcClass ellipticalArc = new EllipticArcClass();

IEnvelope env = new EnvelopeClass();

IPoint lowerLeft = new PointClass();

lowerLeft.X = centerPoint.X - width;

lowerLeft.Y = centerPoint.Y - height;

IPoint upperRight = new PointClass();

upperRight.X = centerPoint.X + width;

upperRight.Y = centerPoint.Y + height;

env.LowerLeft = lowerLeft;

env.UpperRight = upperRight;

ellipticalArc.ConstructEnvelope(env);

IGraphicTrackerSymbol graphicTrackerSymbol = 
this.graphicTracker.CreateSymbol(simpleFillSymbol, null);

int shapeId = this.graphicTracker.Add(ellipticalArc, graphicTrackerSymbol);

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to cast your point to ITopologicalOperator and use the Buffer method to buffer the point by the radius.

Comment: I think this method works for Projected coordinate systems, but will give strange results if you are working with a Geographic coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `ISegmentCollection` solution myself, but you can also recast your `IPoint` or `IGeometry` as `ITopologicalOperator` and call the `Buffer` method.

Comment: -1 for basically taking two of the answers, restating the same, and adding no value.